# Create Container Registry Credential in Ansible AWX for Google Cloud Artifact Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible-awx, google-artifact-registry

I am using ansible awx 23.5.0. I need to configure a container registry credential so that i can create an execution environment who's image comes from Google Artifact Registry.
As far as I understand I need to reference a container registry credential in my execution environment config that will allow me to connect to Google Cloud artifact registry.

However, any such credential must be of type container registry before i can add it to my execution env.

If I create a new container registry credential then i need to supply

- authentication url
- username
- password

I only have a json key for my google service account. How do i supply username and password? and what authentication url is required?

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this [link](https://medium.com/@shrey.batham/setup-awx-ansible-jobs-5556786eb03a) wherein they used Ansible vault credentials to store the service account json key file.

In addition, you may also look this following links that may help you setup the service account on your ansible script:

- [Ansible AWX - Importing Google Cloud Compute instances](https://debugthis.dev/posts/awx/2020-04-03-ansible-awx-importing-google-cloud-compute-instances/)
- [How to pass(use) google SA json in AWX to run anisble playbook which creates/updates/modify the VM in gcp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72659973/how-to-passuse-google-sa-json-in-awx-to-run-anisble-playbook-which-creates-upd)